# Configure iOS Watchkit/Extension for Parse iOS SDK

Tags: parse-platform

I have deployed own Parse server on Scalingo following below link of Parse example server. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

Now I am developing a iOS watch app for what I was following [This Link](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-local-data-sharing-for-apple-watch-and-app-extensions/) from Parse to share PFUser credentials among containing app and watch.

This how is my app delegate in containing app.

```
[Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.abc.xys"];
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration>  _Nonnull configuration) {
        configuration.applicationId = @"myiosapp";
        configuration.clientKey= @"myiosappclientkey";
        configuration.server= @"https://myiosapp.scalingo.io/parse";
    }]];
```

This how I am initializing Parse in my Watch

```
[Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.abc.xys"
                                         containingApplication:@"com.abc.myapp"];
    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];

    [Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration>  _Nonnull configuration) {

        configuration.applicationId = @"myiosapp";
        configuration.clientKey= @"myiosappclientkey";
        configuration.server= @"https://myiosapp.scalingo.io/parse";
    }]];
```

But this seems not to get the `PFUser` which i logged in containing app.

**PS**: It is working fine when I use `[Parse setApplicationId:@.......` for app hosted on Parse.com  but when I use own Server with above `[Parse initializeWithConfiguration....` it does not work.

Comment: what is enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.abc.xys" ??

Comment: Enable DataSharing With Group Identifier. You set the Group Identifier in the Project Properties. Target-> Capabilities->App Groups. For this your Developer account be linked with Xcode (can be free) and your app Bundle Identifier must have been registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Finally got the solution I was looking for. I just included 
`configuration.applicationGroupIdentifier=@"group.abc.xys"` in the block instead of using `[Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.abc.xys"];`
And it worked. Here's how I initialize Parse in my app delegate

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration>  _Nonnull configuration) {
        configuration.applicationGroupIdentifier=@"group.abc.xys";
        configuration.applicationId = @"myiosapp";
        configuration.clientKey= @"myiosappclientkey";
        configuration.server= @"https://myiosapp.scalingo.io/parse";
    }]];
```

And Here's How I initialize Parse in my extension

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration>  _Nonnull configuration) {
    configuration.applicationGroupIdentifier=@"group.abc.xys";
    configuration.containingApplicationBundleIdentifier = @"com.iparagons.Swenee";
    configuration.applicationId = @"myiosapp";
    configuration.clientKey= @"myiosappclientkey";
    configuration.server= @"https://myiosapp.scalingo.io/parse";
}]];
```

**Note: you have to make sure you set `applicationGroupIdentifier` and `containingApplicationBundleIdentifier` before `configuration.applicationId = @"myiosapp";`**